# import txt with date and time

Tags: python, datetime, import

I want to import a txt file that looks like this:

```
time and date   discharge (m3/s)    
1-6-2009 9:50   0    
1-6-2009 9:55   0    
1-6-2009 10:00  0    
1-6-2009 10:05  0    
1-6-2009 10:10  0    
...
```

between the date and time there's a space and between the time and the value there's a tab. How can I import it in python with the date and time as one value? My script looks like this:

```
import scipy    
import matplotlib.dates

kwargs=dict(delimiter =(''),\    
            converters= {0: matplotlib.dates.strpdate2num('%d-%m-%y'),\    
                         1: matplotlib.dates.strpdate2num('%H:%M:%S')},\  
            skip_header= 4,\    
            names=True,\    
            )

catsdata=scipy.genfromtxt('test_tab.txt',**kwargs)    
print catsdata
```

Comment: try to split it, it will get ride of space/tab:
`file2 = open('D:/data.txt', 'r')`
`doc = file2.read()`
`doc=doc.split()`
`print doc`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple method, I'm just printing the data

```
import datetime
f = open('discharge.txt','r')
dis = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i in dis:
  if i.startswith("time"): continue
  dis_date, discharge_rate = i.split('\t')
  discharge_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(dis_date),"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
  print "Date", discharge_date
  print "discharge rate", discharge_rate
```

Output:

```
Date 2009-06-01 09:50:00
discharge rate 0    

Date 2009-06-01 09:55:00
discharge rate 0    

Date 2009-06-01 10:00:00
discharge rate 0    

Date 2009-06-01 10:05:00
discharge rate 0    

Date 2009-06-01 10:10:00
discharge rate 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently someone beat me to a solution, which should probably be marked as the solution. However, here is my solution wrapped into a function:

```
from datetime import datetime

def read_data(filename):
    data = []
    with open(filename) as input_file:  
        for line in input_file:
            if not line.startswith('time and date'):
                date_time, discharge = line.split('\t')
                data_item = {'date': datetime.strptime(str(date_time.strip()), "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"), 'discharge': discharge.strip()}
                data.append(data_item)
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = read_data('input.txt')
    for item in data:
        print("Date: {0}, discharge: {1}".format(item['date'], item['discharge']))
```

The solution basically does the same thing as Rolf of Saxony's solution, but written a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas:

```
D = pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep="\t")

D["time and date"]=pd.to_datetime(D["time and date"],format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
```

Output:

```
        time and date  discharge (m3/s)    
0 2009-06-01 09:50:00                     0
1 2009-06-01 09:55:00                     0
2 2009-06-01 10:00:00                     0
3 2009-06-01 10:05:00                     0
4 2009-06-01 10:10:00                     0
```